# Logstash: removing all the nodes of a given name, in any position of a json

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would need to create a kind of regular expression to remove all the properties in a json matching the name "source_user_id", since such property is at different levels of the json. E.g.

```
filter
{
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["[extended_tweet][entities][media][0][source_user_id]", "message"]
        remove_field => ["[extended_tweet][extended_entities][media][0][source_user_id]", "message"]
...
```

I read that I can do something like:

```
remove_field => ["[%{source_user_id}]", "message"]
```

But that will only match at the first level.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can probably write your own ruby code that does this and put it inside a [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html).